# Can we put a flat metric on any subset of $\mathbb{R}^D$ that's diffeomorphic to an open subset on $\mathbb{R}^d, d < D?$ (just checking!)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^D$ is diffeomorphic to an open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d, d <D.$ Let $\phi: V\to U$ be a diffeomorphism. It seems pretty obvious, but I'm just checking to ensure I didn't miss anything: we can induce a flat metric on $V$ by pulling back the Euclidean metric from $U$ onto $V,$ right? If it's right, then we can easily put a flat metric on $\mathbb{S}^2 -\{(0,0,1)\}, $ am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: You do not even need a diffeomorphism, a local diffeomorphism will suffice. Also, no need to embed your $V$ in some ${\mathbb R}^D$, you can work with abstract smooth manifolds.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for the pointers, and yes you're absolutely right about working with abstract manifolds, and also local diffeomorphism.